# How to wrap text in TextView with background image

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

So in first look at xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twEventDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@drawable/title_event"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Short text"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twCountParticipants"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="bottom|end"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twMaxParticipants"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="bottom|end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="/5"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How you can see I have horizontal LinearLayout and few TextViews. When the first textView in yellow cloud has long text it's look pretty fine.
[good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWQoK.png)

But if text in this TextView is short.. in this way all isn't good
[bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV1JS.png)

So how I make background of this TextView wrap text correctly?
P.S. I tried do it with relative layout, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/twCountParticipants"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/twCountParticipants">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twEventDescription"
        tools:text="bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/twCountParticipants"
    tools:text="1/"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/twMaxParticipants"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/twMaxParticipants"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/twMaxParticipants"
    tools:text="4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need an auto resizable TextView,

```
<com.yourapp.AutoResizeTextView 
        android:id="@+id/twEventDescription"
        tools:text="bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The **AutoResizeTextView** class,

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.Layout.Alignment;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AutoResizeTextView extends TextView {
private interface SizeTester {
    /**
     * 
     * @param suggestedSize
     *            Size of text to be tested
     * @param availableSpace
     *            available space in which text must fit
     * @return an integer < 0 if after applying {@code suggestedSize} to
     *         text, it takes less space than {@code availableSpace}, > 0
     *         otherwise
     */
    public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSpace);
}

private RectF mTextRect = new RectF();

private RectF mAvailableSpaceRect;

private SparseIntArray mTextCachedSizes;

private TextPaint mPaint;

private float mMaxTextSize;

private float mSpacingMult = 1.0f;

private float mSpacingAdd = 0.0f;

private float mMinTextSize = 20;

private int mWidthLimit;

private static final int NO_LINE_LIMIT = -1;
private int mMaxLines;

private boolean mEnableSizeCache = true;
private boolean mInitiallized;

public AutoResizeTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
}

public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();
}

public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    mPaint = new TextPaint(getPaint());
    mMaxTextSize = getTextSize();
    mAvailableSpaceRect = new RectF();
    mTextCachedSizes = new SparseIntArray();
    if (mMaxLines == 0) {
        // no value was assigned during construction
        mMaxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
    }
    mInitiallized = true;
}

@Override
public void setText(final CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    super.setText(text, type);
    adjustTextSize(text.toString());
}

@Override
public void setTextSize(float size) {
    mMaxTextSize = size;
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void setMaxLines(int maxlines) {
    super.setMaxLines(maxlines);
    mMaxLines = maxlines;
    reAdjust();
}

public int getMaxLines() {
    return mMaxLines;
}

@Override
public void setSingleLine() {
    super.setSingleLine();
    mMaxLines = 1;
    reAdjust();
}

@Override
public void setSingleLine(boolean singleLine) {
    super.setSingleLine(singleLine);
    if (singleLine) {
        mMaxLines = 1;
    } else {
        mMaxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
    }
    reAdjust();
}

@Override
public void setLines(int lines) {
    super.setLines(lines);
    mMaxLines = lines;
    reAdjust();
}

@Override
public void setTextSize(int unit, float size) {
    Context c = getContext();
    Resources r;

    if (c == null)
        r = Resources.getSystem();
    else
        r = c.getResources();
    mMaxTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(unit, size,
            r.getDisplayMetrics());
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
    super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
    mSpacingMult = mult;
    mSpacingAdd = add;
}

/**
 * Set the lower text size limit and invalidate the view
 * 
 * @param minTextSize
 */
public void setMinTextSize(float minTextSize) {
    mMinTextSize = minTextSize;
    reAdjust();
}

private void reAdjust() {
    adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
}

private void adjustTextSize(String string) {
    if (!mInitiallized) {
        return;
    }
    int startSize = (int) mMinTextSize;
    int heightLimit = getMeasuredHeight() - getCompoundPaddingBottom()
        - getCompoundPaddingTop();
    mWidthLimit = getMeasuredWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft()
        - getCompoundPaddingRight();
    mAvailableSpaceRect.right = mWidthLimit;
    mAvailableSpaceRect.bottom = heightLimit;
    super.setTextSize(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
            efficientTextSizeSearch(startSize, (int) mMaxTextSize,
                    mSizeTester, mAvailableSpaceRect));
}

private final SizeTester mSizeTester = new SizeTester() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSPace) {
        mPaint.setTextSize(suggestedSize);
        String text = getText().toString();
        boolean singleline = getMaxLines() == 1;
        if (singleline) {
            mTextRect.bottom = mPaint.getFontSpacing();
            mTextRect.right = mPaint.measureText(text);
        } else {
            StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, mPaint,
                    mWidthLimit, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult,
                    mSpacingAdd, true);
            // return early if we have more lines
            if (getMaxLines() != NO_LINE_LIMIT
                    && layout.getLineCount() > getMaxLines()) {
                return 1;
            }
            mTextRect.bottom = layout.getHeight();
            int maxWidth = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++) {
                if (maxWidth < layout.getLineWidth(i)) {
                    maxWidth = (int) layout.getLineWidth(i);
                }
            }
            mTextRect.right = maxWidth;
        }

        mTextRect.offsetTo(0, 0);
        if (availableSPace.contains(mTextRect)) {
            // may be too small, don't worry we will find the best match
            return -1;
        } else {
            // too big
            return 1;
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Enables or disables size caching, enabling it will improve performance
 * where you are animating a value inside TextView. This stores the font
 * size against getText().length() Be careful though while enabling it as 0
 * takes more space than 1 on some fonts and so on.
 * 
 * @param enable
 *            enable font size caching
 */
public void enableSizeCache(boolean enable) {
    mEnableSizeCache = enable;
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
}

private int efficientTextSizeSearch(int start, int end,
        SizeTester sizeTester, RectF availableSpace) {
    if (!mEnableSizeCache) {
        return binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
    }
    String text = getText().toString();
    int key = text == null ? 0 : text.length();
    int size = mTextCachedSizes.get(key);
    if (size != 0) {
        return size;
    }
    size = binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
    mTextCachedSizes.put(key, size);
    return size;
}

private static int binarySearch(int start, int end, SizeTester sizeTester,
        RectF availableSpace) {
    int lastBest = start;
    int lo = start;
    int hi = end - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
        int midValCmp = sizeTester.onTestSize(mid, availableSpace);
        if (midValCmp < 0) {
            lastBest = lo;
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else if (midValCmp > 0) {
            hi = mid - 1;
            lastBest = hi;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    // make sure to return last best
    // this is what should always be returned
    return lastBest;

}

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start,
        final int before, final int after) {
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
    reAdjust();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldwidth,
        int oldheight) {
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldwidth, oldheight);
    if (width != oldwidth || height != oldheight) {
        reAdjust();
    }
}
}
```